# Return a single row in model, pass it to controller and view - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Sorry for posting such a noob question, but I've had hard times when working with returning a single
row from database and pass it to model. Here's my method from my model:

```
public function test($user_id)
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS test FROM test WHERE user_id = '.$user_id.'");

    return $query->first_row('array');
}
```

Here's an example of my controller with some other returned value from my model:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public $layout;
    public $id;
    public $data = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->output->nocache();

        $this->load->model('subject_model');
        $this->load->model('user_model');
        $this->load->model('survey_model');
        $this->id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');

        $this->data['check_if_already_posted_it_survey'] = $this->survey_model->checkIfAlreadyPostedSurvey('it_survey', $this->id);
        $this->data['check_if_already_posted_lvis_survey'] = $this->survey_model->checkIfAlreadyPostedSurvey('lvis_survey', $this->id);
        $this->data['test']= $this->survey_model->test($this->id);


        $this->layout = 'layout/dashboard';
}
```

I can pass all the values from that data array to my view except "test". I've basically tried everything.

CheckIfAlreadyPostedSurvey method will return
number of rows with num_rows and I can easily print the value from them in my view by writing:

```
<?=$check_if_already_posted_it_survey?>
```

What should I do to print out that "test" in my view?

Thanks in advance and apologizes...

Answer (score 0):

I probably got the question wrong, but have you tried

```
echo $this->survey_model->test($this->id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function test($user_id)
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS test FROM test WHERE user_id = '".$user_id."'");

    return $query->row()->test;
}
```

This will return a single row as an object and then the referenced row name, which in this case is `test`.

The following will also work.

```
public function test($user_id)
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE user_id = '".$user_id."'");

    return count($query->result());
}
```

You also messed up the quoting in your SQL statement.